# gcc compile with python headers [Cython]

Tags: python, gcc, cython

Trying to compile a `.c` file which is obtained by using `cython`

```
cython -3 --embed -o test.c test.pyx
```

The `test.c` file is now compiled to a binary with the following command:

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.10 test.c -lpython3.10 -o test
```

The binary `test` runs sucessfully.

However, while distributing the code to multiple systems, running different versions of Python,

```
gcc -Os `python-config --includes` test.c -lpython3.10 -o test
```

`python-config --includes` can take care of the `-I` part, what about the `-l`?

For some Python versions, it is

```
-lpython3.6m
```

Comment: Have you tried `python-config --help`? It might suggest some other options

Comment: Tried, but of no use.